# Excessive pressure in the fuel return system

Tags: fuel-system, diesel, mercedes-benz

Mercedes-benz w211 cdi 2.7 Diesel (2002 year), There is excessive pressure in the fuel return system, (in engine, fuel return hose was removed itself by pressure ).

Is there valve or something like before fuel tank, which might be disrupted/always closed, which discourages fuel to return back in tank?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! How do you know for sure there is excessive pressure? Are you assuming that because the return hose removed itself? Could it just be that the line weakened somehow and just failed?

Comment: Thank you @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2, Yes I assumed by that, then I manually removed returned hose to fuel tank in back side (under back seat, check please image with link below, not my image, but system seems same), to see if fuel is retirning to back to tank or not, but fuel not returned to the tank at all, instead high pressure again flied off hose itself in front/engine side.

https://www.benzworld.org/cdn-cgi/image/format=auto,onerror=redirect,width=1920,height=1920,fit=scale-down/https://www.benzworld.org/attachments/7ac84030-9de5-4b23-b18d-4770306754fe-jpeg.2664639/

Comment: Updated question and added image from my car, in red cicrle , is that just simple tee, or inside is some regulator/valve?  (which might disrupted).

Comment: Have you actually measured the pressure and know what it should be? To me from your description, there still nothing pointing at it being an overpressure problem but a problem with the line itself, but maybe I'm missing something here.